# Designing REST API Domain Models for different clients in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

.NET API

If I am writing a domain model for a .NET API that will be used by a client e.g a mobile app, is it ok to use an automatically set entity property or a full prop?

For example so the client will be notified of the changes with an `INotify` property or I should just do that in the service layer of whatever client is using the API?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a API, how could you notify the clients using INotify? A web-API (REST or SOAP) is, by definition, a distributed system. You can't notify your clients just using your server's C# classes. Your client could even be written in another language, like a ReactJS app, running somewhere around the globe.

Use a service layer to send notifications to your clients - you'll need to send a server-to-client message with [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction), [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) or another framework - and you can use the setter of the property to trigger this messages.